# Change and hold the background color image view inside the horizontal scrollview

Tags: java, android, share

In my application I have used `ImageView` inside the `HorizontalScrollView` . `ImageView` images are getting from URI(json parsing),and the images are loaded to `ImageView` using universal image loader.
Here my problem is how to change the `ImageView` background for corresponding image on item click.
    thanks in advance

what I have to tried:

```
 String RecentBooks="http://";

 ArrayList<List<String>> arrrecentbooks= new ArrayList<List<String>> ();
```

//HorizontalScrollview created programaticallly

```
HorizontalScrollView scollviewh = new HorizontalScrollView(this);

        View v1=null;

        LinearLayout linear_pmain = new LinearLayout(this);

        linear_pmain.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        //  linear_pmain.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.topshelf));bottomthumbnail
```

//arrrecentbook  contains images parsed fron uri

```
        int length=arrrecentbooks.size();

 for(int j=0;j<length;j++)
        {
            LayoutInflater vii = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            v1=vii.inflate(R.layout.thumbnailrowlayout, null);

            List<String> listitem=arrrecentbooks.get(j);

            String  rimageurl=listitem.get(13); 

            String  rbookprice=listitem.get(10);

 img=(ImageView) v1.findViewById(R.id.imgg);
            TextView txt=(TextView) v1.findViewById(R.id.txtg);
            txt.setText("Rs."+rbookprice+"/-");
            txt.setTypeface(tf,Typeface.NORMAL);    


        img.setTag(new String[]{listitem.get(0),listitem.get(1),listitem.get(2),listitem.get(3),listitem.get(4),listitem.get(5),listitem.get(6),listitem.get(7),listitem.get(8),listitem.get(9),listitem.get(10),listitem.get(11),listitem.get(12),listitem.get(13),listitem.get(14),listitem.get(15),listitem.get(16),listitem.get(17),listitem.get(18),listitem.get(19),listitem.get(20),"recentbooks"});
```

//image loaded to image view

```
            {

                imageLoader=new ImageLoader(this);

                imageLoader.DisplayImage(rimageurl, this, img);
            }
            img.setOnClickListener(myIItemClickListener);

            linear_pmain.addView(v1);
        }

        scollviewh.addView(linear_pmain);

        lrecentbooks.addView(scollviewh);
```

//imgeview on itemclick listener

```
   public OnClickListener myIItemClickListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override

    public void onClick(View v) {


        try{

         RelativeLayout borderlyt=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.Booklyut);

            borderlyt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bgorange);

            String[] Qtag = (String[]) v.getTag();


            Log.d("myItemClickListener", Qtag + "");

            //v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bgorange);

            Intent itemintent = new   Intent(cxt,NoolDashboardDetailPage.class);


            Bundle b = new Bundle();

            b.putStringArray("iarray", Qtag);

            b.putInt("mflag", 0);

            itemintent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.INTENT", b);

            startActivityForResult(itemintent,2);

        }
        catch (Exception e) {

            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: please any one give a solution thank you

Comment: I would suggest you to go with HorizontalListView - https://github.com/MeetMe/Android-HorizontalListView, there are others HorizontalListView also available, so with that you can change background in getview method of adapter class as per your requirement on setonitemclick. Otherwise its difficult to find other children of Scrollview in onclick method with for loop, and change their color.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you would like to highlight the images when touched?

Try the following below your `img.setOnClickListener(myIItemClickListener);`:

```
img.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {                 
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e) {   
        if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            ((ImageView) v).setColorFilter(0x44E79B0E, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
        }
        if ((e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) || (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL)) {
            ((ImageView) v).setColorFilter(null);
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Change '0x44E79B0E' to your desired transparent color.

Let me know, if it works for you.

Comment: your code is working but all clicked image background changed,,but i want to current image background only change remaining image backgrounds are normal ..@sec_aw

Comment: please give a solution for this issue@sec_aw

Comment: @murugalonger What do you mean exactly, are you saying that all images are highlighted when you touch one of them? In this case try setting the ID of the image by your increment variable: `img.setId(j);` before `img.setOnTouchListener`. If this works, I will update my answer. Otherwise you should post all the code around your loop of 'image loaded to image view', so I can have a deeper loook.

Comment: when i click one image that image bg is changed ,when i click next image  the background of this image and previously clicked image also changed ,i want change the bg of currently clicked image ,it doesnot change backgroung until i will click another image@sec_aw

Comment: I can not reproduce this and have the same code working in a similar situation. Could you please edit your question with the code you have so far (the whole loop) and a screenshot of the misbehavior?